# Error using nonce in .htaccess Content-Security-Policy (CSP)

Tags: .htaccess, php

I am attempting to use Content-Security-Policy nonce and its generating an error.

The Error via console.log:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-eM7IckhPhRx5dBGXZhwsgAKulpq/euetK0YPweqUKX4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. **Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.**

I also tried using mod_unique_id instead of using PHP set env but it throws internal server error.

What am i doing wrong?

My Code :

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
Header set Connection keep-alive
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

SetEnv MY_CSP_NONCE "<?php echo $_SERVER['MY_CSP_NONCE']; ?>"

Header always set Content-Security-Policy "expr=default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' require-trusted-types-for 'script' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.facebook.com https://www.twitter.com https://www.instagram.com 'nonce-%{ENV:MY_CSP_NONCE}' 'strict-dynamic' 'wasm-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; video-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com data:; style-src 'self' style-src-attr 'self' 'nonce-%{ENV:MY_CSP_NONCE}'; base-uri 'none'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self'; sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups; media-src 'self'; worker-src 'self https://*.cloudflare.com'; manifest-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com; form-action 'self' https://www.paystack.com; font-src 'self' data:; upgrade-insecure-requests"

Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; report-uri https://www.example.com/csp-report-endpoint"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin-allow-popups"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "same-site"
SetEnvIf Referer "^https://storage.googleapis.com" CORP_EXEMPT
Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-same-origin"
Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none" env=CORP_EXEMPT
Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "unsafe-none" "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m!\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|avif|mp4|webm|m4a|ogv)$!"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index$ ./index.php
RewriteRule ^about$ ./about.php

RewriteRule ^404$ ./404.php
RewriteRule ^500$ ./500.php

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404

IndexIgnore *
```

my cookiesetter.php - Where nonce is stored to be included in every script

```
  <?php 
  $nonce = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(64)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
  putenv("MY_CSP_NONCE=$nonce");
  ?>
```

and index.php

```
  <?php include "cookiesetter.php" ?>

  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
  bla bla bla
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <script nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>">
  bla bla bla
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I have not checked it, but I highly doubt that you can use PHP code in the Apache `SetEnv` directive.

Comment: Have you tried [previous solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624598/how-to-implement-content-security-policy-with-wordpress-nonces-in-php-using-php)?